# symfony/dependency-injection conflict with symfony/console

Tags: symfony

I have a magento2.2.6 website I tried to update. Now I endup with this error:

> symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.5].

I tried and looked at several forums and issues, also changed some versions but no good result. Problems with conflicts stays and I'm running out of options.

```
.{    Problem 

  - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
  - magento/framework 102.0.0 requires symfony/console ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.0].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.1].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.2].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.3].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.4].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.5].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.6].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.7].
  - symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.8].
  - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/framework 102.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.0].
  - Installation request for symfony/dependency-injection 3.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/dependency-injection[v3.3.0]

}
```

any ideas

Comment: Did you follow upgrade installations notes from the vendor?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve above-mentioned issue first you have to run the following command

**Step 1**

```
composer config preferred-install dist
composer config sort-packages true
composer config prefer-stable true
```

**Step 2**

```
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.0 --no-update
```

**Step 3**

```
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.0 --no-update
```

**Step 4**

```
php -r '$autoload=json_decode(file_get_contents("composer.json"), true); $autoload["autoload"]["psr-4"]["Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\"]= "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"; file_put_contents("composer.json", json_encode($autoload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));'
```

**Step 5**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update
```

**Step 6**

```
composer update
```

**Step 7**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I did every step, this is the result:

after composer update

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/magento2-base 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.3.0].
- Conclusion: remove symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0
- magento/magento2-base 2.3.0 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.0].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.1].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.2].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.3].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.4].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.5].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.6].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.7].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.8].
- symfony/dependency-injection v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.9].
- Installation request for symfony/dependency-injection 3.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/dependency-injection[v3.3.0].
```